# Loading a context

Tags: entity-framework, objectcontext

Have I understood this correctly please.

When you are running a web application to view pages and you create an instance of the context is that instance loading all the database date into it?

If it does does that not take up a lot of memory a blog with five years of blogs could have 1,500 to 2,000 (or more)post in it, with all the comments tags etc that would be a great deal of data.

So what does happen when you create the instance of a context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A context only loads the records that you request, so when you first instantiate one it will be empty and won't perform any queries against the database until you tell it to.  Any entities you load through it will (usually) be cached within the context, though, so they use more and more memory every time you run a query and can become very large over time.

For that reason, and because contexts are relatively cheap to instantiate, it's a good idea to only keep them alive while you actually need them, and dispose of them as soon as you're done.  This is part of the "unit of work" pattern -- basically using a new context for each set of operations that go together as one unit or transaction.

**Edited to add:**

If you're performing read-only queries (i.e. you just want to display data, you don't need to make changes and save them back to the database), you might check out non-tracking queries (e.g. the [`.AsNoTracking()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method if you're using a `DbContext`/`DbSet`, or the [`MergeOption.NoTracking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.mergeoption.aspx) property if you're using an `ObjectContext`/`ObjectSet`) -- that will avoid caching the results in the context, increasing performance and reducing memory use.

Comment: Thank you that has help a lot, I need to change my code to only open the context when needed at the moment a page opens the context when it loads and when it has finished closes it again which could mean I had a very big context in deed.  Thanks

Comment: Actually that's a pretty common way of doing it -- one context per page request.  Unless you're doing a *lot* of processing, that's usually fine.  It uses some memory, but it can also have advantages like avoiding repeated database queries, and hopefully the whole thing is over with pretty quick anyway.  The real danger is if you try to share one context for the entire application (so that it persists between requests) -- then it can get seriously bloated, there are extra concurrency issues, and the memory doesn't get released.

Comment: Thanks that's saved a weeks work in the admin adding and disposing of contexts